# How to fix stacked mega menu where scroll is not present

Tags: html, css

Basically when you reduce the size of the tab to act as a responsive website, I have stacked the mega menu options. However you cannot scroll to see the other options in the mega menu. How would I fix this.

Example:
[image]

You can see that I cannot scroll to view the other options in the mega menu.

```css
.navBar {
    font-family: Arial;
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.navBar > a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menuDropDown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.menuDropDown > #menuButton {
    font-size: 12px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}

#menuButton:hover, .navBar > .menuDropDown:hover > #menuButton {
    background-color: #CCC;
    color: #1B315E;
}

.menuContent {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: none;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.menuDropDown:hover > .menuContent {
    display: block;
}

.menuColumn {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #CCC;
    height: 250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

#menuColumnHeader {
    color: #1B315E;
}

.menuColumn > a {
    float: none;
    color: #1B315E;
    padding: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.menuColumn > a:hover {
    background-color: #DDD;
}

.menuRow:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .menuColumn {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

```html
     <div class="navBar">
        <div class="menuDropDown">
            <button id="menuButton" title="Site Navigation"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i> Menu</button>
            <div class="menuContent">
            <div class="menuRow">
                <div class="menuColumn">
                    <h5 id="menuColumnHeader" title="Home Workspace">Home Workspace</h5>
                    <a href="#" title="Welcome"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i> Welcome</a>
                    <a href="#" title="Timetable"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> Timetable</a>
                    <a href="#" title="Help"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i> Help</a>
                    <a href="#" title="Dashboard"><i class="fas fa-chart-line"></i> Dashboard</a>
                </div>
                <div class="menuColumn">
                </div>
                <div class="menuColumn">
                </div>
                <div class="menuColumn">
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `max-height` based on the screen height and enable the scroll:

```css
.navBar {
    font-family: Arial;
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.navBar > a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menuDropDown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.menuDropDown > #menuButton {
    font-size: 12px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}

#menuButton:hover, .navBar > .menuDropDown:hover > #menuButton {
    background-color: #CCC;
    color: #1B315E;
}

.menuContent {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: none;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    max-height:100vh;
    overflow:auto;
}

.menuDropDown:hover > .menuContent {
    display: block;
}

.menuColumn {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #CCC;
    height: 250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

#menuColumnHeader {
    color: #1B315E;
}

.menuColumn > a {
    float: none;
    color: #1B315E;
    padding: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.menuColumn > a:hover {
    background-color: #DDD;
}

.menuRow:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .menuColumn {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="navBar">
        <div class="menuDropDown">
            <button id="menuButton" title="Site Navigation"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i> Menu</button>
            <div class="menuContent">
            <div class="menuRow">
                <div class="menuColumn">
                    <h5 id="menuColumnHeader" title="Home Workspace">Home Workspace</h5>
                    <a href="#" title="Welcome"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i> Welcome</a>
                    <a href="#" title="Timetable"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> Timetable</a>
                    <a href="#" title="Help"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i> Help</a>
                    <a href="#" title="Dashboard"><i class="fas fa-chart-line"></i> Dashboard</a>
                </div>
                <div class="menuColumn">
                </div>
                <div class="menuColumn">
                </div>
                <div class="menuColumn">
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: It works to a certain point but it will hide the last two options of the menu like so https://imgur.com/a/nhVS1Cb. How could I fix that

Comment: @user10341225 reduce the height slightly, try 90vh for example or reduce more if it's not enough